# vs emulator works but application doesn't work properly

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created new blank app in xamarin and i didn't change anything in code view. 
When I try to run app. Emulator works good but app doesnt run in emulator. I am using VS 2015 Enterprise Version:14. My operating system is Win10 Enterprise

[image: Emulator]-[VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWiW1.png)

Comment: Anıl, can you provide some details, errors in the output?

Comment: That's the reason why i created this post. Because there  are no errors. It just showes these in the pics. @vivien-chevallier

Comment: and All I have outputs are these;

1>Starting deploy 5" JellyBean (4.2) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Starting emulator 5" JellyBean (4.2) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Validating emulator arguments...
1>Determining if emulator is already running...
1>Preparing virtual machine...
1>Launching emulator...
1>Emulator launched successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click on solution. Select Configuration Manager. Select Deploy.

[image]

Sometimes it gets stack (check green bottom bar in visual studio). If green bar stays full and doesn't go away restart emulator.

Another reason can be that there is no MainLauncher Activity is defined.